# Symbolicate fails for 7.1.1 .ips crash file in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode5, crash-reports

Symbolicate does nothing on a crash file from an App Store deployed app.

I received a .ips file from the end user. It looks like a .crash file inside, so I renamed it and it imported into the Organizer. I assume the crash logs were renamed for some reason, but Xcode won't take it until it was renamed. Does it need special processing?

Symbolicate never gets any of my or system library symbols. I noticed in the console that Stderr for [symbolicatecrash] reported a lot of "Did not find executable for dsym ## Warning Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version..."

I've tried manually running the symbolicate several ways with no result.

I don't know where symbolicatecrash is supposed to look for the system library symbols (UIKit etc.)

The biggest red flag I see in this area is that I don't have a ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1 directory. Where can I get that refreshed on my machine?

UPDATE:
I believe my problem is that I was not able to build and run with an iOS 7.1.1 device connected to Xcode before I submitted to the App Store. Can I force Xcode to get the 7.1.1 symbols from an iOS image or the DeveloperDiskImage.dmg?